# Regex to split the string by first slash & comma with condition

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I need two different Regex, to split the strings, For the following scenarios.
Using ***Java*** platform.

**1. Needs to Split by only first "/"  and if the slash comes within "{}" braces then its wont be consider 
   And also I need to truncate starting and ending braces "{}" only if it comes like example c).**

### a)

```
input: "Response/CartResponse/{StatusData/ResponseCode,RespMessage,{ArrivalMethods/AvailableArrivalMethod/AvailableArrivalMethodName,AvailableFFMCenter}},{ServiceHeaders/clientSessionKey},{Shoppingcart/OrderId,CatalogId}";

output: 
"Response"
"CartResponse/{StatusData/ResponseCode,RespMessage,{ArrivalMethods/AvailableArrivalMethod/AvailableArrivalMethodName,AvailableFFMCenter}},{ServiceHeaders/clientSessionKey},{Shoppingcart/OrderId,CatalogId}";
-------------
```

### b)

```
input: "CartResponse/{StatusData/ResponseCode,RespMessage,{ArrivalMethods/AvailableArrivalMethod/AvailableArrivalMethodName,AvailableFFMCenter}},{ServiceHeaders/clientSessionKey},{Shoppingcart/OrderId,CatalogId}";

output: 
"CartResponse"
"{StatusData/ResponseCode,RespMessage,{ArrivalMethods/AvailableArrivalMethod/AvailableArrivalMethodName,AvailableFFMCenter}},{ServiceHeaders/clientSessionKey},{Shoppingcart/OrderId,CatalogId}";
-------------
```

### c)

```
input: "ArrivalMethods/{AvailableArrivalMethod/AvailableArrivalMethodName,AvailableFFMCenter}";

output: 
"ArrivalMethods"
"AvailableArrivalMethod/AvailableArrivalMethodName,AvailableFFMCenter"
```

**2. Split by comma and if the comma comes within "{}" braces then it wont be consider
   And also I need to remove "{}" as in the following examples.**

```
input: "{StatusData/ResponseCode,RespMessage,{ArrivalMethods/AvailableArrivalMethod /AvailableArrivalMethodName,AvailableFFMCenter}},{ServiceHeaders/clientSessionKey},{Shoppingcart/OrderId,CatalogId}";  

output: 
"StatusData/ResponseCode,RespMessage,{ArrivalMethods/AvailableArrivalMethod/AvailableArrivalMethodName,AvailableFFMCenter}"
"ServiceHeaders/clientSessionKey"
"Shoppingcart/OrderId,CatalogId"



input: "ResponseCode,RespMessage,{ArrivalMethods/AvailableArrivalMethod/AvailableArrivalMethodName,AvailableFFMCenter}";

output: 
"ResponseCode"
"RespMessage"
"ArrivalMethods/AvailableArrivalMethod/AvailableArrivalMethodName,AvailableFFMCenter";
```

Truncating  braces is different in both cases.

Comment: How can example items (b) and (c) be distinguished, just from the starting "ArrivalMethods" token?  I recommend attempting a solution for each type of input and then rephrasing your question for help on one that gives you specific problems...

Comment: Thanks Maerics for the quick response. For my first case Split by slash always gives two tokens. The example(b) have the 2nd token with three enclosed {} sets but the example (c) have the 2nd token with only one enclosed {} set. I mean that the Second token need to be striped when its come with only one brace set{} of string.But in my secound case is needs to strip every starting and ending braces of all tokens.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between case a,b and c is that a and b have embedded {} inside the {}, and c doesn't. Bad news, that cannot be achieved by a single regular expression. Even more, guaranteeing the balance of {} would be nightmarish.

Anyway, what you are describing here is basically a language so it is better to build a parser for it (either by hand or by using a tool like ANTLR or JavaCC).

Comment: yes, Your are clear. But I don't know whether I have enough time with these tools. However its very useful and i'm looking the JavaCC. Let me to check it out.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This problem as you have described it can be solved using only string comparisons and manipulations, no regular expressions needed.  Try writing a method which breaks each case into separate conditions and handles it accordingly, e.g.:

```
public String[] parseInput(String s) {
  if (s.startsWith("Response/") || s.startsWith("CartResponse/")) {
    // Examples (1.a), (1.b)
    return str.split("/", 2);
  } else if (str.startsWith("ArrivalMethods")) {
    // Example (1.c)
    String[] ss = str.split("/", 2);
    ss[1] = ss[1].substring(1, ss[1].length() - 1);
    return ss;
  } else if (s.startsWith("{")) {
    // Example (2.a)
    // ...
  }
  return null;
}
```