# Please help me to find Regex to split my string

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, split

**1. Need regex to find a string is whether enclosed by a brace , that may contains brace with in enclosed string.If Yes Then needs to stripe the 1nd and last braces.**
eg:
{StatusData/ResponseCode,RespMessage,{ArrivalMethods/AvailableArrivalMethod/AvailableArrivalMethodName,AvailableFFMCenter}}

INTO
*StatusData/ResponseCode,RespMessage,{ArrivalMethods/AvailableArrivalMethod/AvailableArrivalMethodName,AvailableFFMCenter}*

**2. I need a regex to find a string is whether comma separated of brace sets or not and if  comma separated then it needs to split as follows wwith comma.**
eg:
{StatusData/ResponseCode,RespMessage,{ArrivalMethods/AvailableArrivalMethod/AvailableArrivalMethodName,AvailableFFMCenter}}
,{ServiceHeaders/clientSessionKey},
{Shoppingcart/OrderId,CatalogId}

INTO

*1. {StatusData/ResponseCode,RespMessage,{ArrivalMethods/AvailableArrivalMethod/AvailableArrivalMethodName,AvailableFFMCenter}}
2. {ServiceHeaders/clientSessionKey}
3. {Shoppingcart/OrderId,CatalogId}*

Comment: Isn't this the same question you asked before : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264299/regex-to-split-the-string-by-first-slash-comma-with-condition

Comment: @Nishan. Yes u r correct. Here I try to get answer for the simplified version of the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding problem 1: that cannot be solved with a regex unless you limit the depth of the nesting. Read [this post](http://www.texttoolkit.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=63%3aparsing-balanced-parenthesis-with-regular-expressions&catid=35%3atechnology&Itemid=55) for an example of how to do it with a limit of 3 (and a description of how to do it for other limits). As that example makes clear, this is a monster to do with regex; you're better off doing this in code if that's an option for you.

Comment: Thanks and your idea is good. Already i started to code. still i need small a pattern in it to split the string with comma but within braces will be ignored.